# Using DAO with JDBC

Tags: architecture, jdbc, dao

I have an architecture that looks like this:
(client: android, server: web services axis2)

```
Presentation layer (Android activities and controllers):
    LoginActivity.java

WebServices Layer:
    Services.java

Domain Layer:
    userManagement:
        UserManager.java
    entities (POJOS):
        User.java

Persistence:
    IDaoUser.java
    DaoUserImpl.java
```

Ok. I do this to perform the login:

```
LoginActivity.java:
    call the web service (using AsyncTask)

Services.java
    ...
    public User login(String username, String passwd) {
        return userManager.login(username, passwd);
    }

UserManager.java:
    ...
    public UserManager() {
        IDaoUser dao = new DaoUserImpl();
    }
    public User login(String username, String passwd) {
        return dao.login(username, passwd);
    }
    ...

DaoUser.java
    ...
    public User login(String username, String passwd);

DaoUserImpl.java:
    ...
    public User login(String username, String passwd) {
        /* JDBC stuff */
    }
    ...
```

Is this approach correct? (or at least, does it make sense?).
In DaoUserImpl.java I'm just checking if exists an user with an username and passwd equals to the arguments (again, I don't know if this approach is correct).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general it looks like you're on the track.  Two incremental improvements to suggest:

1. try to see if you can do with fewer layers on the server side - perhaps you could go straight from service to DAO without a separate Manager object.  You probably also don't need separate DAO interface/implementation unless you're planning to have multiple implementations.
2. consider REST services instead of SOAP and JAX-RS instead of Axis.  REST has less transport / envelope overhead so it may work better for you in a mobile application.

See: 
[[iPhone and Web Services]: REST vs SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859278/iphone-and-web-services-rest-vs-soap)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I also think that I have too many layers, but I suppose that as the system grows I will need them. I'm not very familiar with REST, but I'll consider it.

Comment: In addition, I'm using SOAP instead of REST because for the moment I haven't needed to parse any XML (with ksoap2) and I suppose that with REST I will need to parse the reponses.