# Any success using Apache Thrift on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, thrift

Has anybody done or seen a deployment of [Apache Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) in an iPhone app?

I am wondering if is a reasonable solution for a high-volume, low(er)-latency network service for iPhones compared to HTTP.

One noteworthy thing I found is a [bug report](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-549) about running Thrift on the iPhone, which seems to have been fixed. But that doesn't necessarily indicate that it's a done deal.

Answer (score 4):

Thrift and HTTP aren't mutually exclusive.  In fact thrift now ships with an HTTP transport implementation to use.  It's also a really nice way to auto-generate server/client code that avoids a lot of marshalling/unmarshalling boilerplate while still being really fast.  Its internal representation is basically binary JSON, so it's very similar to a RESTful web service (except being easier to code and much, much faster).

So... anyone able to answer the original question?  If not, I'll dive in myself with thrift's included Cocoa support and see how it works on the iphone.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's binary JSON inside, it's much more compact than that.

Answer (score 4):

Just my two cents..

The accepted answer to this question, is an opinion to not use a technology, not an answer of whether it is possible.

Thrift, is an interface definition language, IDL, like Protobuf and Capt'n'Proto. They permit the definition of a client/server/server protocol which is platform agnostic. JSON and Plist don't provide the same level of type conformance.

Having previously lead an iOS team with 10Ms MAU using Google Protobuf v2.5 on iOS, Android, Windows, and server teams, I can attest that IDLs are great on mobile. Apple uses them for syncing iWork content.

My current team uses Thrift for iOS and Android clients, with a mostly Scala backend. I much prefer it to Protobuf.

We send Thrift payloads over HTTPS and WebSockets. Once you have defined (in Thrift) your our wire communication protocol (i.e. frame structure), it's very easy to evolve your APIs.

However, on iOS in particular there are some implementation issues. The current version of the library is quite poorly packaged, and if you hope to make an Objective-C framework (e.g. for iOS 8+), then you will not be able to out of the box with v0.9.2. This is because the library headers include local imports, (`#import "TProtocol.h"` instead of `#import <Thrift/TProtocol.h>`) with no umbrella headers. Worst of all, the Objective-C compiler generates very messy Objective-C classes, also including local imports from the Thrift library.

Some of these issues are pretty damning. It indicates to me that while use of an IDL is very much a good engineering decision, not many iOS teams are using Thrift, unless they're huge with the resources to write their own library.

Comment: Your point about the accepted answer is valid. (Although it itself is a meta discussion, not an answer about Thrift itself.) Note, I accepted the answer over five years ago, before the Stack Overflow policies/guidelines about answers were as clear and well-known.

Comment: @JasonSmith got no issues with it being the accepted answer. I noted that the question was quite old. But SO should be trying to keep it's content up-to-date which was why I added my own two cents :)

Answer (score 2):

I've always disliked frameworks that use a common interface definition that builds out both server and client code.  It keeps both sides too much in lockstep where in reality server API changes must be very flexible in the versions of clients that are communicating with it.

There are helpful libraries that make JSON or PLIST communication over HTTP pretty easy, and decades of debugging and understanding the HTTP protocol and how to use it well.  I would ignore that at your peril.

Comment: Thanks, Kendall. I agree with you about the risks! I am considering a asking a new question: just when and why one would move off of HTTP? To me it is a steep price to pay.

Still, for a successful iPhone app approaching a million users, maybe it's worth bending over backwards to eek out more speed and lower latency. (I am skeptical. Most iPhone apps are data-driven; serialization isn't the problem; latency can't be helped.) Still I want to know the feel from the broader community.

Comment: Specifically, I am considering using a binary serialization over UDP for frequent, non-critical updates from handsets such as location info. I'm still not persuaded but I'm open to it.

Comment: Now that actually sounds like a good use that may not be nearly as easy to do otherwise.  I stand corrected.

Comment: I wanted to add a little more (I saw your last question first).  I think it makes a ton of sense to worry about scalability early on with so many devices potentially hitting you - but the great thing about using HTTP and web services is so many people have thought out scalability carefully before.  That's why I suggest using RESTful web services over SOAP, because there are so many levers you have to help your system deal with large scale quickly...
That said your question about frequent non-critical non-ordered updates are a great way to use UDP exactly the way it was intended.

Comment: Thanks for all your thoughts, Kendall. I'll +1 you even though technically you didn't share a Thrift success story :)  You nailed my main confusion on the matter. HTTP is human readable and has so much tooling built around it and is horizontally-scalable. Most new apps are data-driven and your DB architecture is another matter. How fast you serialize and your carrier protocol seem moot to me. But why are Protobuf and Thrift so popular? Is it a bunch of cowboys who don't know better?

Comment: Is Thrift that popular?  I have not heard of a lot of people using it... but even so I can see people using things like it because of a certain initial convenience.  I just think it kind of binds you later down the road and that's why I avoid it if I can.

Answer (score 2):

I have used thrift's objective c bindings for a large iPhone app with a few million users. As one of the posters mentioned we can use Http which gets the best of both worlds. However there is no asynchronous HTTP client for thrift. We had to build an event based wrapper to allow non-blocking I/O calls. The underlying layer still issues one call at a time which hit us in a big way because we have one server call that takes a long time but it does not block UI flow and another really fast one that does block UI flow. If the underlying layer is busy with the slow command our fast command just has to wait. I am trying to build asyc http in c++ which can then be used on the iPhone but that is someways off from being ready.

Answer (score 1):

Thrift as an external API doesn't make sense. Use it internally rock and roll.

Comment: Evernote actually uses it as an external api and they have millions of users.