# Communication architecture choice in an IOS / Linux application?

Tags: ios, web-services, middleware

I have a software architecture problem.
I have to design an IOS application which will communicate with a Linux application to get the state of a sensor, and to publish an actuator command. The two applications run in a Local network with an Ad-Hoc WiFi connection between the IOS device and the Linux computer.

So I have to synchronize two values between two applications (as described in figure 1). In a Linux/Linux system, I resolve this kind of problem thanks to any publisher / subscriber middleware. **But how can I solve this problem in an IOS / Linux world** ?

[image: Figure 1 : my synchronization problem]

Actually the Linux application embed an asynchronous TCP Server, and the IOS application is an asynchronous TCP client. Both applications communicate through the TCP Socket. I think that this method is a low level method, and I would like to migrate the communication layer to a much higher level Service based communication framework.

After some bibliographic research I found three ways to resolve my problem :

1. The REST Way :

   I can create a RESTful Web Service which modelize the sensor state, and which is able to send command to the actuator. An implementation of a RESTful web service client exists for IOS, that is "RESTKit", and I think I can use Apache/Axis2 on the server side.
2. The RPC Way :

   I can create on my Linux computer a RPC service provider thanks to the libmaia. On the IOS side, I can use xmlrpc (https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc). My two programs will communicate thanks to the service described in the figure below.
3. The ZeroConf way :

   I didn't get into detail of this methods, but I suppose I can use Bonjour on the IOS side, and AVAHI on the linux side. And then create custom service like in RPC on both side.

[image: The RPC Solution]

**Discussion about these methods :**

The REST way doesn't seem to be the good way because : "*The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer*" (from the Chapter 5 of the Fielding dissertation). My data are very fined grain data, because my command is just a float, and my sensor state too.

I think there is no big difference between the ZeroConf way and the RPC Way. ZeroConf provide "only" the service discovering mechanism, and I don't need this kind of mechanism because my application is a rigid application. Both sides knows which services exists.

So my question are :

- **Does XML RPC based method are the good choice to solve my problem of variable synchronization between an iPhone and a Computer ?**
- **Does it exist other methods ?**

Comment: I assume that in the SensorValueChanged call, the linux app is the client and the iOS app is the server. Is that correct?

Comment: I prefer that the server run on the linux computer.

Comment: What I mean is, for SensorValueChanged, does the linux app calls the iOS app?

Comment: In reply to your Question Paul Lalonde : YES.

Answer (score 2):

I actually recommend you use "tcp socket + protobuf" for your application.

Socket is very efficient in pushing messages to your ios app and protobuf can save your time to deliver a message instead of character bytes. Your other high level proposal actually introduces more complications...

Comment: If I understoud well, Proto buff is a Serialization mechanism, so that could be the right ballence between flexibility and code overload. Does it exist a good implementation of protobuff on IOS ?

Comment: Yes, check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601656/using-protocol-buffers-with-objective-c

Comment: A reminder though, if you need to constant change in the message type, you would better use "optional" in the .proto

Answer (score 2):

I can provide no answers; just some things to consider in no particular order.

I am also assuming that your model is that the iOS device polls the server to synchronize state.

It is probably best to stay away from directly using Berkeley sockets on the iOS device.  iOS used to have issues with low level sockets not connecting after a period of inactivity.  At the very least I would use NSStream or CFStream objects for transport or, if possible, I'd use NSURL, NSURLConnection, NSURLRequest. NSURLConnection's asynchronous data loading capability fits well with iOS' gui update loop.

I think you will have to implement some form of data definition language independent of your implementation method (RES, XML RPC, CORBA, roll your own, etc.)

The data you send and receive over the wire would probably be XML or JSON.  If you use XML you would have to write your own XML document handler as iOS implements the NSXMLParser class but not the NSXMLDocument class.  I would refer JSON as the JSON parser will return an NSArray or NSDictionary hierarchy of NSObjects containing the unserialized data.

I have worked on a GSOAP implementation that used CFStreams for transport.  Each request and response was handled by a request specific class to create request specific objects.  Each new request required a new class definition for the returned data.  Interactivity was maintained by firing the requests through an NSOperationQueue.  Lots of shim here.  The primary advantage of this method was that the interface was defined in a wsdl schema (all requests, responses, and data structures were defined in one place.

I have not looked at CORBA on iOS - you would have to tie in C++ libraries to your code and change the transport to use CFStreams Again, lots of shim but the advantage of having the protocol defined in the idl file. Also you would have a single connection to the server instead of making and breaking TCP connections for each request.

My $.02

Answer (score 0):

XML RPC and what you refer to as "RESTful Web Service" will both get the job done. If you can use JSON instead of XML as the payload format, that would simplify things somewhat on the iOS side.

Zeroconf (aka bonjour) can be used in combination with either approach. In your case it would allow the client to locate the server dynamically, as an alternative to hard-coding an URL or other address in the client. Zeroconf doesn't play any role in actual application-level data transfer.

You probably want to avoid having the linux app call the iOS app, since that will complicate the iOS app a lot, plus it will be hard on the battery.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have cherry picked some existing technologies and seem to be trying to make them fit the problem.

> I would like to migrate the communication layer to a much higher level Service based communication framework

Why?

You should be seeking the method which meets your requirements in terms of available resources (should you assume that the client can maintain a consistent connection? how secure does it need to be?) However besides functionality, availability and security, the biggest concern should be how to implement this with the least amount of effort.

I'd be leaning towards the REST aproach because:

- I do a lot of web development so that's where my skills lie
- it has minimal dependencies
- there is well supported code implementing the protocol stack at both ends
- it's trivial to replace either end of the connection to test out the implementation
- it's trivial to monitor the communications (if they're not encrypted) to test the implementaiton
- adding encryption / authentication does not change the data exchange

Regards your citation, no HTTP is probably not the most sensible for SCADA - but then neither is iOS.

Comment: You are right, I didn't explain why I want to migrate my communcation layer to an higher level of abstraction. The main reason is the constant evolution of the "message" that will be transfered from the Ios device to the linux workstation. I don't want to have to design a "language" with on parser at each side of the communcation link because I know by experience that is a source of potentials bugs. I have no security requierments, and the communication can be considered as consistent.